# Tying in to vent in basement

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

What would be the right way to tie into future vent in the basement?

I assume F.V. in the picture is Future Vent - especially as its in the basement, so I would hope nothing is "on" it other than up to to vent. Both blue and red markings are the same pipe. If anything is on the vent stack above, it would be single toilet and sink in bathroom above

I've drawn two ways I can see in blue and red, but not sure if either are allowed or if there is a better way. I don't have enough pipe to tie in a vertical run that I can see so would be a horizontal vent joining a horizontal vent. Blue would be a horizontal extension of the vent pipe for the new vent. Red would be T into the horizontal run of the existing vent pipe for the new vent.

I've only ever seen a horizontal vent joining a vertical stack - not horizontal to horizontal.

This is to vent a new sink and saniflo in the basement. No toilet - just a single utility sink.

Thanks!

[image: Pic1][image: Pic2]